# A counterexample for Polar Calculus in J. M. Borwein A. S Lewis book P70 Q8 (b)

Tags: convex-analysis

The question is:

Suppose P is a cone in E and C is a compact and convex set of a Euclidean space $Y$. $K$ is a cone in $E \times Y$. Prove: 
$$
(K\cap (P \times C))^{\circ} =
(K\cap (P \times C^{\circ \circ}))^\circ
$$
where $C^\circ=\{y|y^T x≤1$ for all $x∈C\}$.

We know that if $C$ is compact and convex, then $C^{\circ \circ}=U_{λ∈[0,1]}λC$.

I have a counterexample:

Let $C=\{1\}$, and $P=R_+$, and $K=R_+ \times \{0\}$.

Then $K\cap (P \times C)=\emptyset$, but 
$K\cap (P \times C^{\circ \circ})=K$.

Therefore,$(K\cap (P \times C))^{\circ}=R^2$. 
$(K\cap (P \times C^{\circ \circ}))^\circ=-K$.

Is my counterexample wrong? Anyone there can help? Thanks.

I think it should be:

$(K\cap (P \times C))^{\circ}=(K\cap (P \times A))^\circ$.

where $A=U_{0<\lambda \le 1} \lambda C$

Comment: Is $(  )^\circ$ denoting complement or interior?

Comment: Or polar? ${}{}{}$

Comment: It is a polar.  The book is " convex analysis and nonlinear optimization".

Comment: $C^{\circ}=\{y| y^Tx \le 1$ for all $x  \in C \}$.   If $D$ is compact and convex, then $D^{\circ \circ}=U_{\lambda \in [0,1]} \lambda D $.